# jQuery add rows dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add rows dynamically through jQuery, but instead of adding 1 row, its adding 2 rows at a time.

Here is the code:

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current_id = 1;
  $('#add').click(function(){
  next_element($('#timesheetrow1'));
 })

 function next_element(element){
 var new_element = element.clone(),
    id = current_id + 1;
    current_id = id;

if (id <7) {
    new_element.attr("id",element.attr("id").split("1")[0]+id);

    $(':input', new_element).each(function(){
      var field_id = $(this).attr("id"),
          field_name = $(this).attr("name");
      $(this).attr("id", field_id.split("1")[0]+id );
      $(this).attr("name", field_name.split("1")[0]+id );
    });
    new_element.appendTo($("#timesheet-rows"));
  }
   };
 });
```

And HTML Code:

```
<div id="timesheet-rows">
    <div id="timesheetrow1" class="timesheet-row">

    <input type="text" id="FinalNumber1" name="FinalPONumber1" width="50" />                                         
    <input type="text" id="FinalAmount1" name="FinalPOAmount1" width="50" />                                           
   </div>

   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Add" class="add" id="add" class="GreenBTN"/>
```

Comment: how many input you want to add?

Comment: Its adding single row, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/Wrz7e/

Comment: just one at a time, right now, its adding 2 rows (timesheetrow2) at a time and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery clone method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) makes a deep copy of the element specified.  By cloning and appending, you'll get exponential growth instead of linear.  I.e., when you add one the first time, you're ok, but the second time, you'll copy the original element and the child you added, so you'll add 2 instead of 1.  Next time, you'll copy the original and its 3 children, and add 4 instead of 1, and so on.

One way to avoid this issue is to use javaScript's [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.cloneNode) instead of jQuery `clone`.  This gives you the option to make it a deep or shallow clone:

```
next_element(document.getElementById("timesheetrow1"));

var new_element = element.cloneNode(false);
```

Comment: Is there any better way to do this? Where I can add rows dynamically too and can append them as FinalNumber1, FinalNumber2 so they are unique for database inserts

Comment: @user2675939 Nothing is stopping you from doing that.  If you need to turn an element into a jQuery selector again, simply use `$(new_element)`.  The key thing is to not do a deep clone, and I don't see any way to avoid that with jQuery.clone().